# Does a form refresh the page on submission?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have the following code for a form:

```
<?php
if ($user_stat->location_id === $destination->destination_id) {
    ?>
    <small class="pull-left">You are here.</small>
    <?php
} else {
    ?>
    <form class="pull-left" action="my_offices.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="office_id" value="<?= $destination->destination_id ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="travel" />

        <a href="javascript:void(0);" role="button" class="badge badge-primary" onclick="$(this).parent().submit();">Travel</a> <small><?= format_money(TRAVEL_COST) ?></small>
    </form>                            
    <?php
}
?>
```

When the link is clicked, it submits the form which in turn causes the following code to execute,

```
if (!Request::check_post('office_id')) {
    echo UI::alert('Sorry, a malformed request was sent.', 'danger');
} else if (!Office::exists(Request::get_post('office_id'))) {
    echo UI::alert('Sorry, this <strong>Office</strong> does not exist.', 'danger');
} else if (!UserOffice::owns($user->id, Request::get_post('office_id'))) {
    echo UI::alert('Sorry, you don\'t own this <strong>Office</strong>.', 'danger');
} else if (Request::get_post('office_id') === $user_stat->location_id) {
    echo UI::alert('Sorry, you are currently situated in this <strong>Office</strong>.', 'danger');
} else {
    $office_id = Sanitize::int(Request::get_post('office_id'));
    $total = $user_stat->money - TRAVEL_COST;

    if ($total < 0) {
        echo UI::alert('Sorry, you don\'t have enough money to travel.', 'danger');
    } else if (UserOffice::travel($user->id, $office_id)) {
        $minus = Database::run('UPDATE user_stat SET money = ? WHERE id = ?', [$total, $user->id]);

        if ($minus) {
            echo UI::alert('You travelled to your <strong>' . Office::get($office_id)->name . '</strong> office.', 'success');
        }
    }
}
```

The important point to is `UserOffice::travel($user->id, $office_id)` which updates a field in a table matching to the respective `$office_id`. The following should clarify what is meant.

**Note:** The changes are reflected in the database, I have confirmed.

I am currently in 'New York' which has an `$office_id` of `3`,

[image]

Notice the 'London' card shows the 'Travel' link whereas the 'New York' card shows the text as defined by the aforementioned `if` statement.

### The Issue

What the intended effect should be that when you click 'Travel' it should switch the texts on form submission, however, that doesn't seem to happen. It only happens when I refresh the page (not through a form submission). The following [GIF](https://gyazo.com/202936c88790440a73211293262e76f9) should clarify what I mean. Notice how it didn't switch the badges of 'Travel' and the 'Your are here.' text. Now, when I explicitly refresh the page you can see the change take effect.

[image]

What causes the changes to not take effect?

How do form submissions work as opposed to page refreshing?

Comment: Why are you submitting your form using JQuery instead of a `submit` input ?

Comment: @gogaz as it (AFAIK) is the only way to do a form submission via the `a` tag and I preferred the style of the `a` tag with the badge classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will presume from your code here that

```
$user_stat
```

variable is already instantiated by the time you try to save to your database, which in turn you use to print your form.

In short, what happens here is:

get $user_stat from database and put it in a variable

change $user_stat in the database

Try to use unchanged version of $user_stat

Before the last step, you should either re-select $user_stat from teh database, or change its value with code, if you want your changes to be visible when the last step comes

Comment: `$user_stat` is instantiated in `prepend.php` which makes sense. Slipped my mind completely.

Comment: It is my pleasure :)